# Slider doesn't show up as I use manipulate function

Tags: r, ggplot2, manipulate

I am using R 4.0 in Windows 10 and the manipulate sliders don't appear to be working with any of the examples that I take from the videos or textbook.

I did not meet any errors while running the code below, everything works perfectly except for not seeing the slider.

Is anyone else experiencing the same issue?

```
library(manipulate)
library(ggplot2)
library(HistData)
myHist <- function(mu){
  g <- ggplot(Galton, aes(x = child))
  g <- g + geom_histogram(fill = "salmon", 
                          binwidth=1, aes(y = ..density..), colour = "black")
  g <- g + geom_density(size = 2)
  g <- g + geom_vline(xintercept = mu, size = 2)
  mse <- round(mean((Galton$child - mu)^2), 3)  
  g <- g + labs(title = paste('mu = ', mu, ' MSE = ', mse))
  g
}
manipulate(myHist(mu), mu = slider(62, 74, step = 0.5))
```

Comment: There is no base or ggplot2 function called `slider`. What packages are you using, other than ggplot2? Do you have some reproducible data that you can share?

Comment: It seems like a bug. Try first running the command `manipulate(plot(1:5, cex=size), size = slider(0.5,10,step=0.5))` and then your code. It works.

Comment: @MarcoSandri It works! Interesting.... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Running the following first:

```
manipulate(plot(1:5, cex=size), size = slider(0.5,10,step=0.5))
```

As suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62982030/slider-doesnt-show-up-as-i-use-manipulate-function/67490839#comment111380622_62982030) by [Marco Sandri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1166684/marco-sandri) resolved the problem for me.